# error in MPI_Ineighbor_alltoall while using MPI_IN_PLACE

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, in-place

Is MPI_IN_PLACE supported for  MPI_Ineighbor_alltoall or is there a problem with the function call? https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Neighbor_alltoall.3.php says that MPI_IN_PLACE is not supported for send? Doe that implicitly mean it is not supported for receive as well?

If I switch the receive buffer to MPI_IN_PLACE the code breaks

```
ierr = MPI_Ineighbor_alltoall( &P( 0 ), P.chunkSize, MPI_DOUBLE, &R(0),        P.chunkSize, MPI_DOUBLE, nbrComm[0], &request );

ierr = MPI_Ineighbor_alltoall( &P( 0 ), P.chunkSize, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_IN_PLACE, P.chunkSize, MPI_DOUBLE, nbrComm[0], &request );
```

with the following error,

```
*** An error occurred in MPI_Ineighbor_alltoall
*** reported by process [3809738753,4575480487799160832]
*** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
*** MPI_ERR_ARG: invalid argument of some other kind
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

Comment: Are the two lines of code shown supposed to be the same? Or are they meant to illustrate a contrast?

Comment: Does the error occur if you call `MPI_Neighbor_alltoall` (the blocking version)? Can you reproduce the error in a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: sorry the first one has a distinct buffer for receiving... I fixed it

Comment: yes, the error occurs in blocking version as well ...

Comment: At https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node202.htm it says "The 'in place' option is not meaningful for this operation." This is for the blocking version so I assume it's true for the non-blocking as well.